# || operator in while condition not working as expected

Tags: c++, operators

So I'm a new programmer and I decided to try and make this game. It is a basic, let's say person v. person game. You enter the amount of each team, in my case Ninjas and Samurai, and then it randomizes the attack chance of each and outputs the winner. Every time I run the program I input the number of each type, and I always get an output of the Ninjas having 0 health, and the Samurai having negative health. How would I be able to have the while loop end when one team gets to 0 health? I've tried using totalNinjaHealth != 0 || totalSamuraiHealth != 0 but the program runs infinitely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    int ninjas;
    int NINJA_HEALTH = 2;
    int NINJA_ATTACK = 2;

    int samurai;
    int SAMURAI_HEALTH = 3;
    int SAMURAI_ATTACK = 1;

    default_random_engine randomGen(time(NULL));
    uniform_real_distribution<float> attackChance(0.0f, 1.0f);

    cout << " *** Ninjas V Samurai *** " << endl;
    cout << "Input amount of Ninjas" << endl;
    cin >> ninjas;
    cout << "Input amount of Samurai" << endl;
    cin >> samurai;

    int totalNinjaHealth = NINJA_HEALTH * ninjas;
    int totalSamuraiHealth = SAMURAI_HEALTH * samurai;

    cout << totalNinjaHealth << endl;

    while (totalNinjaHealth > 0 == true || totalSamuraiHealth > 0 == true)
    {
        if (attackChance(randomGen) > 0.5f) {
            totalSamuraiHealth -= NINJA_ATTACK;
            cout << totalSamuraiHealth << endl;
        }
        else if(attackChance(randomGen) < 0.5f) {
            totalNinjaHealth -= SAMURAI_ATTACK;
            cout << totalNinjaHealth << endl;
        }
    }
    if (totalNinjaHealth == 0) {
        cout << "Ninjas lost all " << ninjas << " Ninjas. Samurai remaining " << totalSamuraiHealth << endl;
    }
    else if (totalSamuraiHealth == 0)
    {
        cout << "Samurai lost all " << ninjas << " Samurai. Ninjas that remain " << totalNinjaHealth / 2 << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Screenshot of what happens when ran:[ConsoleWhenRan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wNnW.png)
Am I using the || operator incorrectly? I thought the || operator waits until one condition is true and then stops, but when I run the code It seems to wait until both either pass, or equal 0 giving the negative output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the && operator. The || is the "or" operator and will evaluate to true when either one or both of the conditions are true. In your case, the while loop will continue to evaluate as long as one of your teams has health > 0. The "and" operator (&&) requires both conditions to be true for the statement to be evaluated as true.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I only have one question, why would the (&&) operator work? If the && operator requires both conditions to be true, doesn't that mean that it will run until both teams are dead because the condition is > 0 for both teams?

Comment: The condition "> 0" is evaluated separately for each team. In your while statement it would evaluate left to right, first checking if totalNinjaHealth > 0 if this is false, then the whole statement is false and it stops. If totalNinjaHealth > 0 is true, then the && operator would check if the second condition is also true, ie totalSamuraiHealth > 0. If this second condition is false, then the whole statement would again evaluate to false and the loop would stop. The && operator requires both the left of the operator to evaluate to true and the right side to evaluate true to return true overall

Answer (score 0):

What happens is:

You run the loop until either of the teams has positive total health. So the total health is for both of the teams is less/equal to zero.

Then you check the healths and you get your answer. It just so happens that in your case one of the teams died with exactly 0 health. In some cases though, the output should show neither the messages.

Comment: Why would the total health of the teams start below zero? I understand that they start as negatives and increase until one is zero. so technically, when it outputs Ninjas lost, it is actually Samurai losing, but why does it start below zero?

Comment: Because the while() works until either of the teams have positive health (I think you wanted it to be both of them).